# Cómo crear un formulario en ASP.NET Web Forms (C#) a partir de una entidad

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

estoy usando Visual Studio y ASP.NET Webforms.

Mi pregunta es, tengo una clase "usuario" que esta mapeada con el orm Entity Framework y que está ya creada en la bbdd.
Yo quiero crear un formulario de registro con los campos de la clase usuario  (nombre, apellidos, email, etc) a partir de esta entidad "usuario" de forma automática, es decir, por ejemplo:

```
Usuario user = new Usuario();
Form formularioRegistro = user->createForm();
```

En otros frameworks si hay esta opción, no sé si en Webforms existe esto que digo.

Gracias.

Comment: La verdad es que no te explicas muy bien, a que te refieres de forma automática? que se cree el formulario y su lógica de manera mágica? Te recomiendo que te leas [ask] y que realices el [tour], despues puedes [edit] tu pregunta con lo aprendido para que podamos ayudarte

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Exacto, que el formulario se genere en base a su entidad , y ya después decidir que campos mostrar y cuáles no en la vista (registro.aspx).
Si, releyendo mi pregunta no me he explicado muy bien. lo siento.

Comment: entonces... explicala mejor... usa el boton [edit] y editala!

Comment: creo que es [esto](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/connector-net-en/connector-net-tutorials-entity-framework-winform-data-source.html) lo que intentas, me equivoco?

Comment: Hola, si creo que puede ser eso. Aunque pensaba que sería más sencillo y directo. Gracias.